# Need help in Error 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to show Error 404 page when users type a wrong url. 
like if they type http://url.com/wrong it will redirect to http://url.com/error404

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://bit.ly/1jbxCcu ?

Comment: @TempestasLudi lmaooo

Comment: depends what framework you are using